# How to write hive script for return result in shell variable in an Oozie coordinator?

Tags: mysql, shell, hadoop, hive, oozie

Then i coordinate my script.sh in an Oozie there is nothing in a variables S.
Here is shell script

```
S=$(hive -S -hiveconf MY_VAR1=$DB -hiveconf MY_VAR2=$avgpay -hiveconf MY_VAR3=$Date_LastDay -hiveconf MY_VAR4=$Date_LastNmonth -f bpxp.hql)

echo $S "S"


S1=( $( for k in $S ; do echo $k ; done ) )
    cntn=${#S1[@]}
    for (( p=0 ; p<$cntn; p=p+5 ))
 do
     `mysql -h$mysqlhost -u$mysqluser -p$mysqlpass $mysqldb -e "INSERT INTO weekstat (timeshift, partnerid, avg_value, processdate, weekday) VALUES ('${S1[p]}', '${S1[p+1]}', '${S1[p+2]}', '${S1[p+3]}', '${S1[p+4]}');"`
done
```

Mysql commands works fine with another variables
Here is bpxp.hql

```
...

    hive -e "select * from ${hiveconf:MY_VAR1}.weekstat;"
```

Then i run script from shell it works fine. I try to use bpxp.hql without this line `hive -e "select * from ${hiveconf:MY_VAR1}.weekstat;"` and write it in shell S=`hive -e "select * from $DB.weekstat;"` but nothing change.
 Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you done is an efficient way, but minor change as mentioned below:

```
S=$(hive -S -hiveconf MY_VAR1=$DB -hiveconf MY_VAR2=$avgpay -hiveconf MY_VAR3=$Date_LastDay -hiveconf MY_VAR4=$Date_LastNmonth -f bpxp.hql)
```

**In bpxp.hql**    keep the query

```
select * from $DB.weekstat;
```

You don't need to mention hive -e in the hql script, the command above will automatically executes and gives you the output, and stores into S.

Please let me correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: Now i have this select * from ${hiveconf:MY_VAR1}.weekstat; in the bpxp.hql and nothing change, last output in variable S is Stdoutput Moved: 'hdfs://nameservice1/~/weekstat/weekday=2' to trash at: hdfs://nameservice1/~.Trash/Current S. It is previous command before select * from $DB.weekstat;

Comment: I was split .hql file to bpxp.hql and bpxpsel.hql which contains "select * from ${hiveconf:MY_VAR1}.weekstat;"  and now i have P=$(hive -S -hiveconf MY_VAR1=$DB -hiveconf MY_VAR2=$avgpay -hiveconf MY_VAR3=$Date_LastDay -hiveconf MY_VAR4=$Date_LastNmonth -f bpxp.hql)
S=$(hive -S -hiveconf MY_VAR1=$DB -f bpxpsel.hql) and get this exception - Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): Delegation Token can be issued only with kerberos or web authentication. Should i create keytab for kerberos authentication?